# How to bake Simple Deform modifier animation for exporting?

Tags: animation, modifiers, baking

I've animated my object with Simple Deform modifier (keyframed Angle property in Bend tab) and i would like to export this animation into game engine via .fbx. If i'm not wrong, i need to bake animations first, but i don't know how to bake modifier animation. "Bake Action" doesn't work, it just removes Simple Deform modifier, but animation is not baked after that.

Edit: I've discovered that i can "Apply As Shape Key", but baking shape keys also seems not to work...

Comment: Have you tried enabling the Baked Animation option in the fbx exporter? It's one of the options when saving the export file.

Comment: Yes, it's enabled. Well, i think i must rig my object with bones and recreate my animation into skeletal one :(